# Finding a particular value in an excel file and its relevant column

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new in VBA and I would like to find the minimum value of a row and return its column number by creating a command button. 
For example, in a row:
3 2 2 4 5 6 7 
I need to return the column number 2, even though 2 appears twice.

my code currently looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myrange As range
Dim answer As Double
Dim f As Range
Dim column1 As Integer

Set myrange = Worksheets("Solver VBA").range("C94:T94")
answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myrange)
MsgBox answer

Set f = Worksheets("Solver VBA").Cells.Find(answer).Column
MsgBox f
End Sub
```

I keep getting the runtime error '91' and yellow highlight on the 3rd last line.

Edit: I have tried these steps as suggested and it works (but it gives me column number 3 instead of 2, which is fine in my case as well):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myrange As range
Set myrange = Worksheets("Solver VBA").range("C94:T94")

Dim answer As Double
answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myrange)
MsgBox answer
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim column1 As Integer
column1 = Application.Match(answer, myrange, 0) + 2
MsgBox column1

End Sub
```

Comment: try `Columns` without `s` or directly use `MsgBox Application.Match(Application.Min(Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94")), Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94"), 0) + 2`

Comment: yes I have tried that, it still returns the same error :(

Comment: hello again, I have tried your suggestion and it works! However, is there a way I will be able to store the number as an integer instead of it appearing on a msgbox? I am planning to use that number to locate a cell on another row and input a value '1'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing it like that (keeping all your variables):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim myrange As Range
  Set myrange = Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94")

  Dim answer As Double
  answer = Application.Min(myrange)

  Dim column1 As Integer
  column1 = Application.Match(answer, myrange, 0) + 2

  Dim f As Range
  Set f = Application.Index(myrange.EntireRow, 1, column1)

End Sub
```

if you need just the range (the cell containing the value) you also can directly use something like that:

```
Set f = Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("B94").Offset(, Application.Match(Application.Min(Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94")), Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94"), 0))
```

or like in my comment to just get the column number:

```
column1 = Application.Match(Application.Min(Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94")), Worksheets("Solver VBA").Range("C94:T94"), 0) + 2
```

Should be self explaining. But if you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider

1. Dimming `f` as **Long**
2. Dropping the `Set`
3. Using **.Column**
4. Keeping the `MsgBox`

You see with **.Columns** you get a Range object. With **.Column** you get a Long.

Comment: I have corrected the relevant parts, however, I am now getting the error: Compile error: Invalid qualifier on the first line `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`
Also, I am unable to get the code to accept .column as .Column (it always changes back to small caps), will that be an issue?

Comment: Have you changed the **Dim** and removed the **Set** ??

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding, I got the error run-time error '9', not compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
MsgBox f
```

to

```
MsgBox f.address
```